# jquery - add text and style to element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add message and css style to element if the PASSWORD/EMAIL fields are empties, but I have problem to get to the right element - "help-block".

What am I doing wrong?

My JavaScript is in an event handler on the SEND button:

```
if (data.errors.password) {
    $(this).closest(".modal-body").find('input[name=password]').next(".help-block").addClass('has-error');
    $(this).parent(".modal-body").find('input[name=password]').next(".help-block").html(data.errors.password);

//  $('#password-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
//  $('#password-group .help-block').html(data.errors.password); // add the actual error message under our input
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="modal-content" action="#">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">PASS</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" >
            <div class="help-block"></div>
            <!-- errors will go here -->
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success submit">SEND<span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you starting from? E.g., in your code at the top, what's `this`?

Comment: js code is at the bottom of the page @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I meant at the top of your question. What is `this`? What is that code running in response to?

Comment: OH, this is the SEND button. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

You're really close with

```
$(this).closest(".modal-body").find('input[name=password]').next(".help-block").addClass('has-error');
```

...but the Send button isn't *in* `.modal-body`, it's in `.modal-footer`.

Instead, you can go all the way up to `.modal-content` with `closest`:

```
$(this).closest(".modal-content").find('input[name=password]').next(".help-block").addClass('has-error');
```

**Example:**

```js
$("button.submit").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".modal-content").find('input[name=email]').next(".help-block").addClass('has-error').text('testing email help');
  $(this).closest(".modal-content").find('input[name=password]').next(".help-block").addClass('has-error').text('testing password help');
});
// For the example, don't actually submit
$("form").on("submit", function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  color: #d00;
}
```

```html
<form class="modal-content" action="#">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">


    <!-- NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
      <div class="help-block"></div>
      <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div>

    <!-- EMAIL -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">PASS</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
      <div class="help-block"></div>
      <!-- errors will go here -->
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success submit">SEND<span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```